# Firebase rule from the standard docs does not validate

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've just simply copy and pasted over a firebase rule from this documentation to implement token revocations. However, the RTDB rule engine does not allow this expression to be published, notice the screenshot below..

I have literally copied this rule from the documentation found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens

The error is shown in the picture below:
[image]

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `|| 0` at the end seems unlikely. Can you show the problematic rules, and the JSON of your database that the rules access? As text please btw, so that we can easily test with your data and rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that looks like it's not going to work. Luckily you can get the same result with a bit more code:

```
".read": "$user_id === auth.uid 
    && (!root.child('metadata').child(auth.uid).child('revokeTime').exists()
       || auth.token.auth_time > root.child('metadata').child(auth.uid).child('revokeTime').val())
```

So instead of using the `|| 0` trick to handle the case where there's no `revokeTime`, this now have an explicit condition for that case.

I also filed a bug to get this fixed in our documentation.

Comment: Thanx for the confirmation!